# How do I remove the dash-star in ipynb

Tags: python, ipython

what is this dash star in ipynb and how can i remove it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those look like tab indicators. The text editor should have an option like "Show tabs" or "Show whitespace" that you could turn off.